# HTML changes not reflecting when running using node and nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am trying to send my HTML file as a response form my server.js, but it is not adapting to my HTML changed even after restarting the server.

I have also tried nodemon.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view cache', true);

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');
    client.on('join', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    client.on('messages', function(data){
        client.emit('thread', data);
        client.broadcast.emit('thread', data);
    });
});

server.listen(7777);
```

Comment: Have you tried `app.set('view cache', false);` instead of `true`?

Comment: Ya I tried using that also, but it is not working

Comment: Seems fine to me... https://repl.it/repls/JuvenileGruesomeDictionaries
Have you tried a different browser and clearing your cache/cookies? Some of the earlier requests you made to the browser could cause it do weird things, for instance if you do a 301 PERMANENT REDIRECT it is hard to reverse...
When in doubt, use `curl`

Comment: yes it is working now thanks for the fix...